# Integrar proyecto Android Studio en TFS 2017

Tags: android-studio, visual-studio-2015, vsts

Quería saber cual es la mejor forma de alojar un proyecto de Android en Team Foundation Server 2017 para versionar el código, hacer commits, etc.

Ya pude hacerlo de una forma, que es agregarlo a mano. Pero no me gusta que debo ingresar al VS2015 cada vez que tenga que hacer el Check-in o mergear cambios.

Vi tambien que existe un plugin (http://java.visualstudio.com/Downloads/androidstudioplugin/Index) pero se integra con Git y la compañia NO quiere utilizar otro versionador que no sea TFS.

Alguna idea? Gracias!

Comment: ¿Que version de tfs tenes?

Comment: La version es TFS 2017

Comment: Mira existe la herramienta TFS Power Tools que te agrega la funcionalidad de realizar todas las tareas que realizas desde el Visual Studio pero desde el file explorer o sea desde el menu contextual de windows como la hace SVN, yo actualmente uso tfs 2015, no se si ya salio la version de TFS Power Tools para la versión 2017 de tfs.

Comment: Voy a investigar esta herramienta, en todo caso me pasaré a TFS 2015 si no me queda otra. Seguiré escuchando recomendaciones. Te agradezco la ayuda!!

Comment: Con 2015 no vas a tener ningun problema, te paso una par de capturas en la respuesta para que veas de lo que estoy hablando!

Comment: Finalmente si me sirvió el PowerTools 2015. Puedo hacer check-in y check-out desde el file explorer hacia el TFS2017. Lo que no me toman son los cambios que realizo en un proyecto Android. Me dice que no tengo cambios para subir cuando si los hice. Se te ocurre algo? Gracias!

Comment: Te fijaste si tenes setado el current source control desde el Visual studio en Opciones-->Source Control, deberia tomartelo, si no cargate una nueva pregunta en asi podes pasar capturas de como te lo muestra el visual studio.

Comment: Ok. me fijo y te aviso. Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con [TFS Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power) podes realizar todas las tareas que realizas desde el Visual Studio pero desde el file explorer o sea desde el menu contextual de windows como la hace SVN, yo actualmente uso tfs 2015. Te adjunto algunas imagenes de como se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

TFS y Git pueden coexistir.

TFS Es la herramienta de Microsoft que te permite entre otras cosas gestionar el control de versiones, seguimiento de tareas, administración de paquetes, integración continua y delivery continuo.

En el caso de control de versiones te permite manejarlo de dos maneras:

- [TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/overview#team-foundation-version-control) (Única opción en versiones antiguas de TFS)
- Git (Añadido en TFS 2013)

En el caso que de todas maneras necesiten usar TFVC, existe la posibilidad de hacer todo por línea de comandos:

[Use Team Foundation version control commands](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands)

Para mostrar los comandos puedes ejecutar lo sgte en el Developer Command Prompt de Visual Studio 2015

```
tf vc help
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, voy a investigar. Saludos!

Comment: Ok, entonces si con ese cmd puedo hacer commits, pull y push hacia TFS, desde mi proyecto Android estaría perfecto. Lo que queremos es meter todo en TFS, ya sea proyectos .NET, Android, etc

Comment: Efectivamente pero si es posible trata de crear el repositorio con Git dentro de TFS, de esta manera  puedes trabajar con la línea de comandos de Git o cualquiera herramienta gráfica de las existentes

Comment: Ok. Lo de Git no será posible xq se decidirá por un solo versionador para todos los proyectos. Igualmente si se puede ya estoy conforme. Gracias!